# regex match line in which the first word repeats elsewhere in the line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a way to match a line that has two or more occurrences of a pattern (a word). Example:

```
abc cde abc dd
```

should be matched because the sequence `abc` is present twice. The sequences are always separated by a space. If it helps, it is enough to test for multiple presence of the first word.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the reason of the 2 downvotes.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I gave you an upvote and aswered tick, i do not know who downvoted you but I have had some issues with certain users at stackoverflow...

Comment: Nobody downvoted me (not yet, at least, ahahah), but someone downvoted you without commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sentence *if it helps, I am ok, to test for multiple presence of the first sequence*, I deduce that your primal interest was in matching the repeated words without such a limitation that the word is at the beginning of the line.

[This](https://regex101.com/r/bGwGdo/1) will match all words which are repeated (it does not match the last repetition):

```regex
(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

For instance, given the line

```
aaa abc dd cde abc dd cde fga dd hello
```

it matches `abc`, `dd`, `cde`, `dd` (yes, it matches the first and second `dd`, as both are followed by another `dd`).

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```regex
^(\w{2,}(?=\s)).*\1.*$
```

### Explanation

`^` means to search the start of a line

`(\w*(?=\s))` this part is the first capturing group, `\w` checks for word characters of any quantity and `(?=\s)` is a positive lookahead to see if it ends with a whitespace.

The following `.*` means there can be any characters of any quantity.

Fianlly, `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group.

`.*$` at the end matches the rest of the line